# How to display/ fire data (sum column values) from SQL Server database in C# WinForm textBoxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to display the sum up certain columns from my SQL Server database into Winforms `textboxes` but I'm facing difficulties and I don't know further.

This how my table in the `database` looks like:

[image]

My C# code:

```
if (combobox1.SelectedText != null)
{
    string CS = (@"Data )

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.Connection = con;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = ("[dbo].[spSalesAnalyse]");
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cbAnalyse.SelectedValue.ToString());
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
         con.Open();
         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
       // Save the results in the DT. Call the adapter statement and fill it in the DT
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                //Fill textBoxes with data in DT
                textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("North");
                textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[1].Field<string>("East");
                textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[2].Field<string>("West");
                ....
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
```

My expectation:

[image]

The Problem: If I debugg till this line `adapter.Fill(dt)`, I do see the records **BUT** they are not getting to my textBoxes. They are empty when debugg reach textBoxes level

Hope I did express myself well

Comment: Have you looked into GROUP BY expression with an aggregate?

Comment: when you run the query manually what do the results look like.. also you do not need `( )` in this line `sqlCmd.CommandText = ("[dbo].[spSalesAnalyse]");` it should just be 
` sqlCmd.CommandText ="spSalesAnalyse";` for starters.. have you even stepped through the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get one textbox value at a time. You could use the `GROUP BY` clause in SQL to fetch your data.

```
SELECT
  Country,
  Region,
  SUM([Sales1]) AS [First Sales],
  SUM([Sales2]) AS [Sec Sales],
  SUM([Sales3]) AS [Third Sales]
FROM 
  [dbo].[tblSales]
GROUP BY Country, Region
```

A single query will return all your results. You can take this results in a `DataSet` and then set the values of the corresponding textboxes by fetching values from the DataSet.

```
//Use query string as show above
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Now that you have records inside your DataSet, you can fill your textboxes.

```
DataRow dataRow = dataset.Tables[0].Select("Country = 'Italy' AND Region = 'North'").FirstOrDefault();
if (dataRow != null) {
    textbox1.Text = dataRow["First Sales"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thnx dude but can you give me an example how? I mean with the dataset :)

Comment: @ Praveen Unfortunately no. I've edited my c# code. Can u please take a look and help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for GROUP BY

**Edited to answer the OPs remark**

```
SELECT region, country
        , SUM (  sales1 ) as [First Sales]
        , SUM ( sales2 ) as [Second Sales]
        , SUM ( sales3 ) as [Third Sales]
 FROM tblSales 
 GROUP BY country, region
```

Comment: But I've three Sales columns and as such how do I set them to the textBoxes? Will be nice if you can edit my sp query so that I get a clue

Comment: I changed it accordingly